# Installed local postfix, Thunderbird unable to use it

Tags: thunderbird, postfix, smtp

In Ubuntu 2011.04, I want to install an SMTP server for development tests, so I did this:

- sudo apt-get install postfix
- Choosed `local` because I only want to access it from my computer
- Entered `nico` (my machine's name, pingable) as mail host name

postfix is running as confirmed by `sudo /etc/init.d/postfix status`.

PROBLEM: I configured Thunderbird to use my `nico` as an SMTP server with user `nico`, but when I send an email a popup appears saying:

> Send Message Error. Sending of message failed.
>   The message could not be sent because connecting to SMTP server nico failed. The server may be unavailable or is refusing SMTP connections. Please verify that your SMTP server settings are correct and try again, or contact the server administrator.

Did I forget something? I was following the simple steps from this [blog post](http://my.opera.com/Contrid/blog/show.dml/478684) (I skipped the "further configuration" part).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically use 'Internet site with smarthost' for postfix running on my laptop, and specify my company's SMTP server as the smarthost.  For a computer that doesn't roam between networks, it would be fine to specify your ISP's SMTP server as the smarthost.  If you have a Google account, you could use Google's SMTP as well.

'Internet site' might also work, but it might run afoul of various spam protections, since it will try to reach each recipient's SMTP server directly.

I'm not sure what 'local' means; can you check (`netstat -tln`) if Postfix is even listening on 127.0.0.1 port 25?  If not, Thunderbird won't be able to talk to your Postfix over TCP.

On the Thunderbird side, specify `localhost` as the SMTP server with no username or password.

Comment: Thanks! Something is listening to 127.0.0.1:25 and I receive a different error after following your last line's advice: `The mail server responded:  5.1.1 <iewvrowijvw@gmail.com>: Recipient address rejected: gmail.com`

Comment: That points to a possible config issue. Out of curiosity, are you on a Residential IP address?

Comment: @Phoenix: I am within a local network, which has a router to the Internet.

Comment: Now the question is _which_ mail server rejected that email -- your own postfix, or your smarthost?